# SQL Server Update error

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have an `Update` query that was working; however, I was not saving the new record first, which was causing issues with primary key constraints between users, when things got busy, for this fairly small application. Now, when the record has been saved with the primary key in the record, the user then enters data into the form, and needs to update the record using this action. The query generates the following error:

> Failed to convert parameter value from string to a decimal.

This is odd because I am not trying to convert it to a decimal. I have found that the error resides at the end of my update query with the parameter `@MyRFA`. Not sure why, that is the primary key that has been inserted, and is also a `Varchar(15)`. `@MyRFA` is a 6-digit number like '112408', and has not had a problem until I decided to try and change things up a bit (I'm doing this in Dev).

Here is my code. I tried to put line breaks in the code for viewing the long SQL line but they would not work, sorry!

```
Open_DB_Con()

Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Update RFA Set [ProjectNo] = @ProjectNo, [ContractNo] = @ContractNo, [EasementNo] = @EasementNo, [SSIDNo] = @SSIDNo, [OrdinanceNo] = @OrdinanceNo, [BA_CTNo] = @BA_CTNo, [FundNo] = @FundNo, [ResolutionNo] = @ResolutionNo, [DeedNo] = @DeedNo, [VendorName] = @VendorName, [Amount] = @Amount, [ProjectDescription] = @ProjectDescription, [Meeting] = @Meeting, [FileName] = @FileName, [Memo] = @Memo, [MayorsApproval] = @MayorsApproval, [RFA_Type] = @MyArea where RFA_Type = @MyArea and TrackNo = @MyRFA", Con)

cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectNo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = Trim(ProjNo.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContractNo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Trim(ContNo.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@EasementNo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Trim(EaseNo.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@SSIDNo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Trim(ssNo.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@OrdinanceNo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Trim(OrdNo.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@BA_CTNo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Trim(baNo.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@FundNo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Trim(FunNo.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ResolutionNo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Trim(ResNo.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@DeedNo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Trim(DeeNo.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@VendorName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 250).Value = Trim(VenNam.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Amount", SqlDbType.Decimal, 19, 2).Value = Trim(txtAmt.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProjectDescription", SqlDbType.VarChar, 250).Value = Trim(ProDesc.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Meeting", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15).Value = Trim(Meet.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@FileName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = Trim(FilNam.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Memo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 3500).Value = Trim(txtMemo.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@MayorsApproval", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15).Value = Trim(MayApp.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@MyArea", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15).Value = Trim(SelArea)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@MyRFA", SqlDbType.VarChar, 5).Value = Trim(RFA)

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Just scanning... The `@Amount` parameter addition is definitely attempting to convert a string to a decimal. May or may not be your issue, but I'd look at it closely.

Comment: dbParameters allow you to tell the Provider what type to expect: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@Amount", SqlDbType.Decimal, 19, 2)` then you passed it a string

Comment: Can you run Sql profiler and review the sent sql script to spot where the error. Sql Profiler should be your friend to such a problems and avoid guessing.

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention, when trying to narrow down the issue, I took the SQL string and put it directly into a SQLQuery on the SQL Server Management Studio to test it with all empty parameters except for the Where clause with just the Primary Key in it:

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention, when narrowing down the issue, I took the SQL string, put it directly into a SQLQuery on the SS Management Studio to test with all empty parameters except for Where clause with just Primary Key in it: Update RFA Set [ProjectNo] = '', [ContractNo] = '', [EasementNo] = ...[Amount] = '', [ProjectDescription] = '', [MeetingDate] = '', [FileName] = '', [Memo] = '', [MayorsApproval] = '', [RFA_Type] = '' where TrackNo = '113409'   and I still get the same error: Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Comment: Is every column in table RFA except for Amount really defined as varchar? And your one line should be `cmd.Parameters.Add("@Amount", SqlDbType.Decimal, 19, 2).Value = CDec(Trim(txtAmt.Text))`